# Not able to read `childChanged`

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to listen for `childChanged` in my app. I have a firebaseStructure like this:

-counters
---currentLoggedInUsers : 4

I want to be able to listen to when currentLoggedInUsers changes.

My best effort is this:

```
 ref?.child("counters").observe( .childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in
            let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : Int] ?? [:]
            print(snapshot) //Prints the correct value when updated

            self.currentLoggedInUsers = dict["currentLoggedInUsers"]! 
     })
```

the `snapshot` prints correctly when updated, but `self. currentLoggedInUsers = dict["currentLoggedInUsers"]!` gives error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

Comment: It's likely crashing because there are other child nodes within the counters node that have values other than Int's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer will depend on whether there are other child nodes stored within counters. So if it just this

```
counters
   currentLoggedInUsers: 2
```

then the following code should be used, keeping in mind that .value will cause the code in the closure to fire immediately.

```
let ref = self.ref.child("counters").child("currentLoggedInUsers")
ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    print(snapshot.key, snapshot.value)
})
```

as it is watching that specific child node for changes.

note self.ref points to my firebase as a class var

To expand a bit, suppose you have other child nodes within counters and you want to watch them for changes as well.

```
counters
   currentLoggedInUsers: 2
   totalUsers: 100
   usersFavFood: Tacos
```

and one way to handle that is

```
let ref = self.ref.child("counters")
ref.observe(.childChanged, with: { snapshot in
    let nodeKey = snapshot.key

    switch nodeKey {
    case "currentLoggedInUsers":
        let count = snapshot.value as? Int ?? 0
        print("logged in users changed to: \(count)")
    case "totalUsers":
        let totalCount = snapshot.value as? Int ?? 0
        print("total Users: \(totalCount)")
    case "usersFavFood":
        let food = snapshot.value as? String ?? "No food for you"
        print("favorite food changed to: \(food)")
    default:
        print("some node changed but it's not handled")
    }
})
```